# Non-Increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ is eventually non-increasing, where 
>   $$a_n=\frac{3n+4}{2n-3},\quad n\ge1.$$

Is it right to say that for $(a_n)$ to be eventually non-increasing $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ and then work out the inequality?

I get it down to $-21\le-4$.

By saying "$\Rightarrow a_{n+1}\le a_n \forall n\ge1$" Is that sufficient?

Comment: You have done a splendid side calculation.  You now need a proof, which begins with "Let $n>1$" and *ends* with $a_{n+1}\le a_n$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note that $\forall n \geq 2$ we have

$$ a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{-17}{(2n-1)(2n-3)} < 0  $$

so that the sequence is strictly decreasing for $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x) = \frac{3x +4}{2x -3}$ then $$f'(x) = \frac{6x -9-6x-8}{(2x -3)^{2}} = \frac{-17}{(2x -3)^{2}} < 0$$ and so your sequence is eventually non-increasing